# How to resolve Wordpress HTTP ERROR 403 Access Denied

Tags: wordpress

I am logged into my wordpress admin dashboard, but when I access any admin function, I get Access to ... was denied You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403

I have been trying to access the export function to export personal data so I can reinstall wordpress again, but I'm not able to access it.